# How do you code merging different executables into a single window frame? Like browsers do?

Tags: c++

OK, so a noob question here: How do you code this functionality that browsers have for example? You open a chrome browser for example and you can open multiple tabs open. Then you can move one tab out of the window and it becomes another window, having its own separate process. Then you can drag that tab into another window and they become one frame? Similar to docking in windows applications, but how do you do it with executables?

Comment: _"having its own separate process"_ In browsers each tab already starts as own process.

Comment: Ok, so how do you merge them?

Comment: I don't know but one way to find out is the code base of firefox or chromium.

Comment: Top-level windows aren't separate processes in browsers. The tab contents are. All top-level windows are usually owned by the same process. The title is also misleading in that all processes are the same executable file underneath. There aren't different exes for "main UI" and "tab content" and "plugin host". Well, the plugin host actually *is* a separate executable in Firefox at least ("plugin-container.exe").

Comment: This is hardly a noob question, by the way. It's very complex functionality, involving lots of interprocess communication that must be carefully designed in order to have acceptable performance.

Comment: It depends on the operating system, but in Windows, you can *just do it*. Nothing in Windows *stops* you from putting one process's window inside a different process's window!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows-specific answer, though I think other OSs work pretty much the same: the `HWND` handle that you get for a window is global. If you send its numeric value to a different process, that process can use it to do things with the window: get its information, resize it, even draw on it. What it can't do is replace its event handler function.

To get process separation like browsers have nowadays, the key is to create a container window and send the handle to the child. The child then creates its own window as a child of the container. The child window simply fills out the entire content area of the container.

This way, the content process is contained within the parent's window, but can handle events.

Now, if you want to drag out a tab into its own top-level window, the parent process creates a new top-level window with all the UI inside, and then re-parents the content container to this new top-level window. The content child follows along.

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell you how to code it, you should search the feature inside the chromium code to know how it's coded but I can tell you how it works:

Inside chromium every tab, extension, utility, etc is a process, each one of these processes is child of the "Browser" process, the "Browser" process manages everything (creating new windows, opening new tabs, closing tabs, destroying windows etc) so, for example, whenever you open a new instance of chromium you are telling the "Browser" process to create a new tab and put it inside a new window.
Every window is managed by the "Browser" process and every tab is managed by a process that is child of the main process.

Now to reply your question: when you drag & drop a tab outside a window you're triggering an event that is caught by the "Browser" process which then create a new window and assign the tab to the new window.

Those informations should give you a hint on how you could develop this feature yourself.

If you want to know more about the chromium architecture I suggest you to read how chromium is designed at https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents